# fix label legend python

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I'm trying to have the same label for 'domains' having the same numbers. how can I do it? I want the same color for each domain number...
[image: please, see plot here]

```
d = {'selected_peaks': [487, 537, 181, 139], 'timeStep': [24250000.0, 26750000.0, 9000000.0, 6900000.0]
   , 'F': [868.7655, 713.4191, 584.4315, 698.3004], 'domain': [2, 2, 3, 3]}

for i in range(len(d['selected_peaks'])):
    plt.plot(d['timeStep'][i], d['F'][i], 'o', label='domain '+str(d['domain'][i]))
    plt.legend()
```

Comment: I would iterate over your data using zip.
`for t, fval, domain in zip(d['timeStep'], d['F'], d['domain']):
  plt.plot(t, fval, 'o', label='domain' + str(domain))`. It's a bit cleaner IMO.

Comment: Also, if you only want each legend entry to appear once, only add the label argument to `plot` if you haven't added the same label before.

Answer (score 3):

Simply create a dictionary of colors and reference them using the `color` parameter.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
d = {'selected_peaks': [487, 537, 181, 139], 'timeStep': [24250000.0, 26750000.0, 9000000.0, 6900000.0]
   , 'F': [868.7655, 713.4191, 584.4315, 698.3004], 'domain': [2, 2, 3, 3], }

colors = {2:'red', 3:'green'}

for i in range(len(d['selected_peaks'])):
    plt.plot(d['timeStep'][i], d['F'][i], 'o', label='domain '+str(d['domain'][i]), color=colors[d['domain'][i]])
    plt.legend()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Although the plot can definitely be created only employing matplotlib, the problem at hand is very suited to present the data as a [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) dataframe and use [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org) to plot.

Just passing the name of the 'domain' column as `hue` parameter automatically creates a color per domain and automatically adds a legend with all the double entries removed. If you don't like the default colors, you can either choose a colormap, create a colormap or give a list of colors as the `palette` parameter. Also appropriate labels for the X and Y axis are automatically set using the column names.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

d = {'selected_peaks': [487, 537, 181, 139], 'timeStep': [24250000.0, 26750000.0, 9000000.0, 6900000.0],
     'F': [868.7655, 713.4191, 584.4315, 698.3004], 'domain': [2, 2, 3, 3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

sns.scatterplot('timeStep', 'F', marker='o', hue='domain', palette='tab10', data=df)

plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: Nice and clean, love it!

Answer (score 0):

Splitting your problem in two answers your question, but it looks not very clean...

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


d = {'selected_peaks': [487, 537, 181, 139],
     'timeStep': [24250000.0, 26750000.0, 9000000.0, 6900000.0],
     'F': [868.7655, 713.4191, 584.4315, 698.3004], 'domain': [2, 2, 3, 3]}


if 2 in d['domain']:
    for i in range(len(d['selected_peaks'][:2])):
        plt.plot(d['timeStep'][i], d['F'][i], 'o', c='black',
                 label='domain '+str(d['domain'][i]))
        plt.legend()
if 3 in d['domain']:
    for i in range(len(d['selected_peaks'][2:4])):
        plt.plot(d['timeStep'][i+2], d['F'][i+2], 'o', c='red',
                 label='domain '+str(d['domain'][i+2]))
        plt.legend()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Specify the color depending on the value of the domain, using a color variable that is then sent to the plt.plot() command:

```
    if d["domain"][i] == 2:
        color = "b"
    elif d["domain"][i] == 3:
        color = "r"
```

And the final code becomes:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

d = {
    "selected_peaks": [487, 537, 181, 139],
    "timeStep": [24250000.0, 26750000.0, 9000000.0, 6900000.0],
    "F": [868.7655, 713.4191, 584.4315, 698.3004],
    "domain": [2, 2, 3, 3],
}
for i in range(len(d["selected_peaks"])):
    if d["domain"][i] == 2:
        color = "b"
    elif d["domain"][i] == 3:
        color = "r"
    plt.plot(
        d["timeStep"][i],
        d["F"][i],
        "o",
        color=color,
        label="domain " + str(d["domain"][i]),
    )

    plt.legend()
```

[image]